# How to input Int array in Line in Python

Tags: python

In Ruby I can use

```
   x = gets.split(" ").map{|x| x.to_i}
```

how to write in Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> x = raw_input("Int array")
Int array>? 1 2 3
>>> map(int, x.split())
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 7):

In python 3.x

```
list(map(int, input().split()))
```

In python 2.x

```
map(int, raw_input().split())
```

Comment: +1, `map()` is also a perfectly good way to do this.

Answer (score 6):

```
x = [int(part) for part in input().split()]
```

In 2.x, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` - this is because in Python 2.x, `input()` parses the user's input as Python code, which is dangerous and slow. `raw_input()` just gives you the string. In 3.x, they changed `input()` to work that way as it is what you generally want.

This is a simple [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) that takes the split components of the input (using `str.split()`, which splits on whitespace) and makes each component an integer.